# Railo How to enter a Servlet mapping url-pattern in resin like in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, railo, resin

I am getting url pattern matching to work in Railo on Tomcat by using this in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/babeswithbraces/posts/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/babeswithbraces/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So if I call the page  `http://localhost:8888/babeswithbraces/posts` OR `http://localhost:8888/babeswithbraces/pages` then the request is correctly handled.

But, my production Railo server is running on Resin. So I am not sure how to do this there?

I have tried adding the same lines to the `app-default.xml` file in `"C:\Railo\conf"` but that does not seem to have made any difference and when the website loads (example: `http://babeswithbraces.com/posts`) it gives a standard 404 page not found error. So obviously something is wrong.

I have tried:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/babeswithbraces.com/posts/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/babeswithbraces.com/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have also tried:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/posts/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

How / where do I get the URL patterns set up correctly for resin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Resin the syntax is:

```
<servlet-mapping url-pattern="[pattern]" servlet-name="[servlet-name]" />
```

So you would need the following entries:

```
<servlet-mapping url-pattern="/posts/*" servlet-name="CFMLServlet" />
<servlet-mapping url-pattern="/pages/*" servlet-name="CFMLServlet" />
```